# How to make Login Page show up on separate page (currently has Aside menu) ASP.net MVC

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Currently when I try to go to the login page, it shows up on a separate page at the beginning(see pic at expected result). When I click "log off" or if user is not authorized, the login page shows up with my sites menus around it.

I also noticed if I just refresh the page it goes to the correct full page login screen.

I Looked into my Web.Config and everything looks good there:

`<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>`

I recently changed all my login procedures and believe the problem persists in ReturnUrl but I can't seem to find the problem. I compared my old code to new and don't see any changes.

**Account controller:**

```
// GET: /Account/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        EnsureLoggedOut();            
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        // Store the originating URL so we can attach it to a form field
        var viewModel = new LoginViewModel { ReturnUrl = returnUrl };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();
        try
        {
            user = DBcontext.Users.Where(u => u.Email.Equals(model.Email)).Single(); // where db is ApplicationDbContext instance

        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            // the user is not exist
            return View("The user does not exist.");
        }

        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

        SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }

    // POST: /Account/LogOff
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }


    private void EnsureLoggedOut()
    {
        // If the request is (still) marked as authenticated we send the user to the logout action
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            LogOff(); 
    }
}
```

**Login View:**

```
@model LoginViewModel
@{ViewBag.PageId = "extr-page";
ViewBag.PageClass = "animated fadeInDown";}

@section topright{<span id="extr-page-header-space"> <span class="hidden-mobile">Need an account?</span> <a href="@Url.Action("register", "account")" class="btn btn-danger">Create account</a> </span>
}

<div id="content" class="container">
<div class="row">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_LoginText"); }
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-4">
        <div class="well no-padding">
            <form action="@Url.Action("Login", "Account")" method="POST" id="login-form" class="smart-form client-form">
                <header>
                    Sign In
                </header>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ReturnUrl)
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationBootstrap()
                <fieldset>
                    <section>
                        <label class="label">E-mail</label>
                        <label class="input">
                            <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>
                            <input type="Email" name="Email" value="demo@email.com">
                            <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right"><i class="fa fa-user txt-color-teal"></i> Please enter email address/username</b>
                        </label>
                    </section>

                    <section>
                        <label class="label">Password</label>
                        <label class="input">
                            <i class="icon-append fa fa-lock"></i>
                            <input type="Password" name="Password" value="demo">
                            <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right"><i class="fa fa-lock txt-color-teal"></i> Enter your password</b>
                        </label>
                        <div class="note">
                            <a href="@Url.Action("forgotpassword", "Account")"><i class="fa fa-frown-o"></i> Forgot password?</a>
                        </div>
                    </section>

                    <section>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="RememberMe" value="true" checked="checked">
                            <input type="hidden" name="RememberMe" value="false" />
                            <i></i>Stay signed in
                        </label>
                    </section>
                </fieldset>
                <footer>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        Sign in
                    </button>
                </footer>
            </form>
        </div>
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("_SocialMedia"); }
    </div>
</div>
```

**Expected result:** (also the result at upon first visit to the site.)

[image]

**Current Result:**
    [image]

Thanks for any help in advance.

**UPDATE:** 
This seems to be an authentication problem. If user is authenticated then the Menus show up. Started a new thread trying to resolve authentication problem [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56012271/how-to-unauthenticate-current-user-asp-net-mvc-identity).

Comment: Well, when you logout you're redirecting to Index. What does the Index view and action look like?

Comment: @Jasen I have decorated my index controller with an authentication attribute. Once it realizes that no user is logged in it takes them to Account\Login. I have tried to change the logout to Account\Login manualy and it did not help. Thanks for looking into this

Comment: I think you are having a templating issue here, you can make changes to your ViewStart.cshtml page to show a different/cleaner template for login

Comment: @Bosco I took your advice and started a new _layout for the login screen but the problem still persisted. I have since found that this is an authentication problem that remains to be solved. I have started a new thread to solve it.

Comment: Let me see your _ViewStart.cshtml