# How to unauthenticate current user ASP.net mvc Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity

When a user goes to my site they get the login page. Once they successfully login they can logoff and a different user can login. However, if the user clicks the back button while logged in it goes to the login page. At this point a new user can no longer login. I receive an anti-forgery token error.

I have tried to logoff any user that goes to the login page. I have tried different ways to logoff. I even tried to `Session.Abandon();`

**Account controller:**

```
// GET: /Account/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        EnsureLoggedOut();            
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        // Store the originating URL so we can attach it to a form field
        var viewModel = new LoginViewModel { ReturnUrl = returnUrl };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();
        try
        {
            user = DBcontext.Users.Where(u => u.Email.Equals(model.Email)).Single(); // where db is ApplicationDbContext instance

        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            // the user is not exist
            return View("The user does not exist.");
        }

        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

        SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }

    // POST: /Account/LogOff
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    { Session.Abandon();
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }                

}
```

**Login View:**

```
@model LoginViewModel
@{ViewBag.PageId = "extr-page";
ViewBag.PageClass = "animated fadeInDown";}

@section topright{<span id="extr-page-header-space"> <span class="hidden-mobile">Need an account?</span> <a href="@Url.Action("register", "account")" class="btn btn-danger">Create account</a> </span>
}

<div id="content" class="container">
<div class="row">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_LoginText"); }
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-4">
        <div class="well no-padding">
            <form action="@Url.Action("Login", "Account")" method="POST" id="login-form" class="smart-form client-form">
                <header>
                    Sign In
                </header>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ReturnUrl)
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationBootstrap()
                <fieldset>
                    <section>
                        <label class="label">E-mail</label>
                        <label class="input">
                            <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>
                            <input type="Email" name="Email" value="demo@email.com">
                            <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right"><i class="fa fa-user txt-color-teal"></i> Please enter email address/username</b>
                        </label>
                    </section>

                    <section>
                        <label class="label">Password</label>
                        <label class="input">
                            <i class="icon-append fa fa-lock"></i>
                            <input type="Password" name="Password" value="demo">
                            <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right"><i class="fa fa-lock txt-color-teal"></i> Enter your password</b>
                        </label>
                        <div class="note">
                            <a href="@Url.Action("forgotpassword", "Account")"><i class="fa fa-frown-o"></i> Forgot password?</a>
                        </div>
                    </section>

                    <section>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="RememberMe" value="true" checked="checked">
                            <input type="hidden" name="RememberMe" value="false" />
                            <i></i>Stay signed in
                        </label>
                    </section>
                </fieldset>
                <footer>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        Sign in
                    </button>
                </footer>
            </form>
        </div>
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("_SocialMedia"); }
    </div>
</div>
```

I was hoping for when a user hits the back button and he/she goes to the login page the previous user gets logged off.

[image]

**Update 1:**
To be clear I am not worried about a user that just logged off and hits the back button. On the contrary, my site breaks when a user logs in successfully and then hits the back button. It takes them back to the Login page but no username or password works because of the aforementioned Anti-Forgery error.

**Update 2:**
I tested the code in IE and it had no problems. Upon further research it looks like Chrome is saving the authentication cookie when I hit the back button. However, when I properly logoff the cookie is destroyed. I thought when the login  page loads I was calling the LogOff method but its not deleting the cookie. I will continue to research this problem. Maybe someone has experience with this?

**Update 3:**
 I did notice that the cookie was not deleted when I hit the back btn. When I properly logoff the cookie gets deleted. When I not cache the page utilizing Shoe's method below, the cookie does get deleted upon hitting the back btn. However, I still get the anti-forgery token error. What's interesting is that I have a part of the header that pops up on the login page. That header should only come up when a user is authenticated. There should also be an aside menu to pop up on authentication. But it doesn't. I'm wondering if I have an async problem that's causing both problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent browser back button after logout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21930487/how-to-prevent-browser-back-button-after-logout)

Comment: @Heretic no that's the opposite of what I'm looking for. If I hit the back button from Home/Index it will go to the login page but no one can login due to the anti-cross forgery error.

Comment: @Heretic The link you posted was for Webforms. I have read everything and it does not pertain to my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing a combination of two things.

**Problem 1:** 
I noticed that When I hit the back btn and the login view was displayed, the previous users cookie was not destroyed. This only occured in chrome but not in IE. This was solved with `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]` attribute on my `Login` `Get` (Thanks @Shoe). See code below.

*Login:*

```
// GET: /Account/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        EnsureLoggedOut();

        // Store the originating URL so we can attach it to a form field
        var viewModel = new LoginViewModel { ReturnUrl = returnUrl };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

**Problem 2:**
The second problem was that once the login view was displayed, I called a method to signout the user with `AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);` and `Session.Abandon();`. This was not unauthenticating the user until I hit the refresh button for a reason I don't understand. Not until I add a second step to clear the principal to ensure the user does not retain any authentication by adding `HttpContext.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(string.Empty), null);` to my EnsureLoggedOut method. See code below.

*EnsureLoggedOut Method:*

```
private void EnsureLoggedOut()
    {
        if (AuthenticationManager.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            //SignOut the current user
            AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            Session.Abandon();

            // Second we clear the principal to ensure the user does not retain any authentication
            HttpContext.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(string.Empty), null);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because the page is getting cached and the anti-forgery token that was generated for an anonymous user can't be validated against the logged in user.

Try sticking the `OutputCache` (`ResponseCache` in core) attribute on your `Login` `GET` and this will set the right headers to not cache the page.

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I wish I read this b4 the hour of research. I did notice that the cookie was not deleted when I hit the back btn. When I properly logoff the cookie gets deleted. When I not cache the page the cookie does get deleted upon hitting the back btn. However, I still get the anti-forgery token error. What's interesting is that I have a part of the header that pops up on the login page. That header should only come up when a user is authenticated. There should also be an aside menu to pop up on authentication. But it doesn't. I'm wondering if I have an async problem that's causing both problems.

Comment: Check `User.IsAuthenticated` on your login view. If it's `true` then your anti-forgery token is still going to throw that error. try `if(User.IsAuthenticated){ EnsureLoggedOut(); RedirectToAction("Login"); }` that way a new request is generated

Comment: Yes that is good practice. Thank you for all your help. I have posted the solution below.